# Hyper-V Wireless Bridge Disappears After Sleep

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, boot-camp, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro x64 on a MacBook Pro via bootcamp. I've setup a Hyper-V for a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM. For networking I've setup a Hyper-V External Switch to my wifi, which creates a network bridge between the WiFi card and the vEthernet external switch. Everything works fine, unless the laptop goes to sleep. 
When resuming from sleep the Network Bridge is gone, which causes the vEthernet external switch to say that the network cable is unplugged. If I reboot the machine the Network Bridge reappears, and all is well with the world. Obviously, needing to reboot after sleep isn't the solution though. Is there a fix to keep the Network Bridge from going away after sleep?
Thanks!